# How to make notification lights turn off automatically when new email is read from another platform?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, notification-led

I'm using a Samsung S3 and I currently have the notification LED indicator option ON when an email arrives.

Is there a way to make the flashing blue light stops when I read this new email from another platform (Thunderbird for example)?

For example: Unread new email inbox : Flashing
             New email recently read: Stop flashing

Thanks!

Comment: Could be possible with Tasker. You might check for unread message count, then turn off the led.